# Unexpected json result while calling the surveymonkey api

Tags: c#, json, surveymonkey

When calling the surveymonkey api I'm using
 `{\"survey_id\":\"47625442\"," +"\"fields[]\":\"['url']\"}"` 
as the json data the server needs to complete my request. while it is returning the data it is required it is not returning the additional URL i believe i am requesting. Does anyone know why this wouldn't give me this back?

**EDIT https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_collector_list this is the call im trying to make if this helps**

Comment: unclear what you are asking..

Comment: I'm not getting back the url that i am requesting. Am i formatting the json string incorrectly for this to work?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking but, the json in your question `{"survey_id":"47625442","fields[]":"['url']"}` is not valid.

Comment: Hows this. The post request that im making to the api takes json as data to get information about the surveys back. How should i be formating this json so that it has the survey id as a string and the fields with "url" as an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments:  Your JSON formatting is off, so the API doesn't understand that you're asking for the URL.

For an understanding of what's going on, take a look at the example request in the link you provided; note the format of the **fields** section.

Try again, this time with:

```
{"survey_id": "47625442", "fields": ["url"]}
```

...which with the escapes will look like this....

```
    {\"survey_id\": \"47625442\", \"fields\":[ \"url\" ]}"
```

Comment: wow thanks so much you fixed my problem. i would up vote you but my reputation kinda sucks.